# Does "php bin/magento setup:upgrade" install sample data too?

Tags: php, magento2, magento-2.0

I have experienced this problem twice with one of my magento 2 setup. Running in developer mode, it sometime asks me to upgrade Database schema or data when it shows that modules are out dated.

Following the instructions i ran `php bin/magento setup:upgrade` which updates the schema but installs the sample data too.

Please share your inputs on this.

Comment: do you have sample data module installed with setup?

Comment: no, it was not. But gets updated as soon as ran upgrade.

Comment: no, it was not. But gets updated as soon as ran upgrade.

Answer (score 2):

If you have the sample data module added to your magento2 this command will install the sample data, if you took the version without sample data, this will not install sample data

see here the 2 versions:
https://www.magentocommerce.com/download

See here the instructions how to install the sample data module:
http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/install-gde/install/sample-data-after-composer.html

Answer (score 2):

command::php bin/magento setup:upgrade

This commands updates the all default and custom modules . in any custom module there will be **Setup** Folder.

All four files(i.e Installschema.php,InstallData.php,UpdateSchema.php,UpdateData.php) in Setup folder will be executed automatically

If there is some sample data in InstallData.php Then only sample data will be added in model(i.e db table)

Answer (score 0):

`php bin/magento setup:upgrade` doesn't install anything. This command updates database schema and data for modules you have already installed.

To install sample data modules, run `php bin/magento sampledata:deploy` then run `setup:upgrade`